# Changing Text Color of Array Elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am trying to change text color on hover, but getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at HTMLDivElement` error

```
<a data-tab="Tab 1">
  <div class="tab-link__text">Tab1</div>
</a>
<a data-tab="Tab 2">
  <div class="tab-link__text">Tab2</div>
</a>


 let tabLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-link__text');
 let tabLinksArr = Array.prototype.slice.call( tabLinks )

  tabLinksArr[0].style.color = "red"; //THIS WORKS

  for (i=0; i < tabLinksArr.length; i++) {
    tabLinksArr[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        tabLinksArr[i].style.color = "red"; // THIS DOES NOT
    });
  }
```

Styling works outside the for loop but not inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your snippet is that `i` is set to `2` after the for loop completes, meaning `tabLinks[i].style.color = "red"` is trying to set the style of `tabLinks[2]`, which doesn't exist. This can be resolved by keeping a reference to the appropriate `tabLink`:

```js
let tabLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-link__text');

for (i = 0; i < tabLinks.length; i++) {
  let tabLink = tabLinks[i];
  tabLink.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    tabLink.style.color = "red";
  });
}
```

```html
<a data-tab="Tab 1">
  <div class="tab-link__text">Tab1</div>
</a>
<a data-tab="Tab 2">
  <div class="tab-link__text">Tab2</div>
</a>
```

Other things to keep in mind:

1) Modern style prefers single quotes `'` to double quotes `"`

2) Arrow functions `=>` instead of `function` keyword

3) declare your variables `let i`

4) prefer `array.forEach()` or `for(el of array)` instead of `for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`

5) Prefer modifying element classes instead of styles directly.

```js
let tabLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-link__text');
[...tabLinks].forEach(tabLink =>
  tabLink.addEventListener('mouseover', () =>
    tabLink.classList.add('hovered')));
```

```css
.hovered {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a data-tab="Tab 1">
  <div class="tab-link__text">Tab1</div>
</a>
<a data-tab="Tab 2">
  <div class="tab-link__text">Tab2</div>
</a>
```

Comment: So what is the convention. Using @julien's event target, or your keeping reference technique?

Comment: I prefer avoiding using `e.target` because it can be unclear what `e.target` will refer to when you're listening to bubbled events (e.g. nested child is clicked, but you're event listener is on the parent container. But this is just preference to what you / your team finds readable.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` (and similar methods) return `HTMLCollection`s, which do not implement the array API (e.g. `forEach`). Wrapping the collection in `[...collection]` converts it to an array and allows using `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the variable `i` in the function context is now equal to `tabLinks.length` because the function is called before the for loop is done (you can `console.log` the i variable in your event listener).
So because tabLinks doesn't have the index `tabLinks[tabLinks.length]` (the last index is `tabLinks[tabLinks.length - 1]`) then you have the error `Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`, so you cannot use i variable on this place, but you can use event target instead :

```
for (i=0; i < tabLinks.length; i++) {
    tabLinks[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
        e.target.style.color = "red";
    });
  }
```

Hopes it helps

Comment: You should try to avoid using the undeclared `e` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.
I checked this code working properly.

```html
<a data-tab="Tab 1">
  <div class="tab-link__text">Tab1</div>
</a>
<a data-tab="Tab 2">
  <div class="tab-link__text">Tab2</div>
</a>

<script>
let tabLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-link__text');
tabLinks.forEach(tabLink => {
     tabLink.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
           tabLink.style.color = "red"
     });
});
</script>
```

**Thank you**